# Change WebKitWebSettings in Go cgo

Tags: c, webkit, go, cgo

I'm using go-webkit and I have a instance of webkitsettings, how can I change the settings?

I'm trying to do something like this

**main.go**

```
webview := webkit.NewWebView()
settings := webview.GetSettings()
settings.SetEnableJavascript(false)
webview.SetSettings(settings)
```

**go-webkit**
Snippet from https://github.com/mattn/go-webkit/blob/master/webkit/webkit.go#L370

```
type WebSettings struct {
        glib.GObject
}

func (settings *WebSettings) SetEnableJavascript (flag bool) {
//I tried various ways
//C.g_object_set?
}
func (v *WebView) SetSettings(settings *WebSettings) {
        C.webkit_web_view_set_settings(v.getWebView(), C.to_WebKitWebSettings(settings.Object));
}
func (v *WebView) GetSettings() *WebSettings {
        return &WebSettings{glib.GObject{unsafe.Pointer(C.webkit_web_view_get_settings(v.getWebView()))}}
}
func NewWebSettings() *WebSettings {
        return &WebSettings{glib.GObject{unsafe.Pointer(C.webkit_web_settings_new())}}
```

}

**Webkit API:** 1.0
http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebSettings.html

```
/* Create a new websettings and disable java script */
WebKitWebSettings *settings = webkit_web_settings_new ();
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(settings), "enable-scripts", FALSE, NULL);

/* Apply the result */
webkit_web_view_set_settings (WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(my_webview), settings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebSettings` embeds [`glib.GObject`](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/1928f15c55e59f51f650d448f092c517d0d64074/glib/glib.go#L462) which in turn implements the [`Set`](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/blob/1928f15c55e59f51f650d448f092c517d0d64074/glib/glib.go#L487) method (see [godoc](http://godoc.org/github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib#GObject)).

So `g_object_set` should translate in your case to `settings.GObject.Set` or, as the method set 
of `GObject` is exported to `WebSettings`, you can simply do

```
settings.Set("enable-scripts", false)
```

Comment: Oh man! I can't believe I missed that. All this time it was already implemented. Thanks!